# How to search and treat the result with Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I 'm was looking for a module to make research in tweeter (the research bar) and take the profile id/username of all the profile in link with the research.

I have seen the api tweepy, i think the answer i'm looking for is hide in thes 2 fonction :
search_users
_lookup_users

```
#!/usr/bin/env   python                                                                       
     #-*-coding:utf-8-*-                                                                                                                                                                       

import tweepy, time, sys

CONSUMER_KEY = '#'

CONSUMER_SECRET = '#'
ACCESS_KEY = '#'

ACCESS_SECRET = '#'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

liste2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

i = 0

while (liste2[i] != '\0'):

  file = api.search.users(liste2[i])

  print "passed"

  i = i + 1
```

I still got nothing for list all the profile match with the search.

the doc : https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py

Thanks :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? Do you want to search all users whose username contain some string? Also, note that the search using an API and the search from the bar on the website will not produce the same results.

Comment: My answer had a typo, it is now corrected and should work.

Answer (score 0):

You linked to the source code, not to the doc. The doc can be found [here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html); be careful though, as it is not very up-to-date.

You can just do:

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = "#"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "#"
ACCESS_KEY = "#"
ACCESS_SECRET = "#"

#Twitter credentials
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
#api = tweepy.API(auth_handler=auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

liste2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

for element in liste2:
    results = api.search_users(q=element)
    #results now contains a lot of `user` objects, let's iterate through it to see the usernames
    for user in results:
        print(user.screen_name)
```